# How can I fill an array with unimportant values (after declaration)?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a class which has a member which is a Vector. Thus, the declaration is in the protected members area. I have a constructor which takes (among other things) an int, which indicates how big the Vector will be. I will be adding individual elements to the array at (effectively) random indices.

My problem is: How do I initialize the Vector with generic values (0's, or their struct equivalent) after the declaration? Or failing that, how can I insert elements at an index which may be greater than the current size of the vector?

This is my (simplified) class:

```
class DataSample {
protected:
    std::vector<data_value> data;
public:
    DataSample(int n){
        //TODO: initialize Vector here
    }
    void insertValue(int index, struct data_value value){
        //TODO: insert value at index into Vector
    }
}
```

I'm currently using vector.reserve(n) to allocate enough space (to reduced resizing delay), but it doesn't change the actual size or contents.

data_value is a simple struct which just contains a uint32_t value.

Comment: @JaredDykstra How so?

Comment: Not a duplicate, since the size isn't known at compile time (it takes the value from a network socket, it could literally be anything).

Comment: I misunderstood your question... Thought the size was known in advance

Comment: No worries, but that's why the question exists in the first place. If I knew the size, I could just put that in the declaration and it would be trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to initialize the `vector` in a member initializer list:

```
DataSample(int n) : data(n) {

}
```

This initializes the `vector` using a constructor that takes in a size, then creates a `vector` of `n` elements, all of which take on the default value for the appropriate type.

Answer (score 3):

[`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) has a [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) that allows you to specify the size of the vector.  If you use

```
DataSample(int n) : data(n) { }
```

Then `data` will have the size `n` and all of the elements in the vector will have the default value.